# Express.js add middleware to only one special route

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having a route which needs to work with files. So I'm using [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable) middleware.
This is how I'm adding formidable middleware.

```
app.use(formidableMiddleware());
```

But adding this middleware in this way will cause it to affect all other routes too. Is there any way to add the middleware to only one specific route without affecting others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain the middleware you wish to add to the route:

```
app.get('/mypath', formidableMiddleware(), (req, res) => {
  // rest of the code
})
```

Or if you've multiple routes to specify:

```
app.use(['/patha', '/pathb', '/pathc'], formidableMiddleware());
```